# Get computer name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

To get the computer name I wrote something like below:

```
Dim client As System.Net.IPHostEntry
client = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST"))
label1.text=client.hostname
```

This code works on the server machine but on the client machine its not working.

Is there any another way to find the computer name.

Comment: What error do you get? What do the `Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST")` return?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the request from the client, for example:

```
label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
```

See more about [HttpRequest.UserHostName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname.aspx)

Comment: Using this code I can see the IP address of the machine, but I need the computer name.

Comment: So do a DNS lookup? Same principal as in your question.

Comment: @Abhishek Is this what you want? http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Network/PerformingaReverseDNSLookup.htm

Comment: THANKS, BUT I AM NOT USING C#. I AM USING VISUAL BASIC LANGUAGE.

Comment: NO NEED TO SHOUT. It's still the same principal in C# or VB.NET and you ALREADY have the answer in the code snippet you posted which means you probably just copied it from somewhere without actually understanding what it does which won't do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

The code below just like your is the *best* attempt at getting the clients DNS machine name:

```
Dim host As IPHostEntry
'Get the server variable value
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Item("REMOTE_HOST"))
```

What you are doing by using the "REMOTE_HOST" server variable is asking for the name of the host *making the request*. Well read that last part again and it provides the answer of why it will not always yield the proper result.

If you have your website on a webfarm that has a load balancer sitting in front of it, you will get the value of the **load balancer** and not of the *original* client making the request. The "REMOTE_HOST" should probably have details stating it's the *last* host making the request. This is why using that server variable is unreliable.

It is also a security risk so JavaScript does not allow getting this information either so that's not an option as well. Just purely for informations sake, one old school brute force way to get this was by using an ActiveX control but that is not a viable option either. The point is unless you are on a domain and can do a reverse lookup by IP, you probably have no consistient and relieable way of getting the *original* client's machine name 100% of the time.